# How do I install a second disk of a pc game?

Tags: wine, games

On a few pc games, they take 2 disks to install. I have Lububtu, and am trying to use wine to install them, which works fine, until it asks for the second disk. I put it in, and it says that there are no files on that disk, and make sure I have the right disk. There is also a box that lets me type in what file I want to use. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that some things struggle because they've used a `/media/oli/Disk 1` style path. When you unmount the first disk and replace it you'll end up with `/media/oli/Disk 2`... Which naturally breaks everything.

CDs *should* also be mounted at `/media/cdrom` which won't change. Assuming that holds true for you, the easiest solution is to launch the installer from there.

Might also be good to check `winecfg` to make sure you haven't accidentally hard-coded in a disk name into a drive allocation.